# The etymology of "snooze"

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

I was looking up the etymology of the word ***[snooze](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=snooze)***, and the Etymology Online suggested it was unknown.

> 1789, cant word, of unknown origin, perhaps echoic of a snore. Related: *Snoozed*; *snoozing*. The noun meaning "a short nap" is from 1793. *Snooze-alarm* is from 1965.

I thought this was odd, because the verb to fall asleep in Czech is *[usnout](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usnout)*, which is very similar. I was wondering if there is a connection via Proto Indo-European, like the connection between the PIE médʰu (honey wine) and the English *mead* (Honey Wine), the Czech *med* (honey) or the Iranian *mei* (wine). Anyone know the PIE reconstruction for sleep or related words?

Is there any connection between *snooze* and *usnout*?

Comment: I very much doubt we got the word from Czech. Maybe it's a "portmanteau" of  ***snore*** and ***doze***, but that's pure speculation on my part. It goes back to at least 1789, according to the OED - but we didn't come up with ***snooze buttons*** on alarms until 1965.

Comment: I don't expect that we got it from Czech, but I was wondering if there is a connection via Proto Indo-European, like the connection between the PIE médʰu (honey wine) and the English Mead (Honey Wine), the Czech Med (honey) or the Iranian Mei (wine).   Anyone know the PIE reconstruction for sleep or related words?

Comment: _Snooze_ is associated with the nose, like other [words with the  2D + 3D Convex `SN-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf), e.g, _sniff sneeze snort snore snuff snicker snorkel sniffle snub snob snoop snarl snoot snivel snigger sneer snot snout_.

Comment: Doing a little bit of research, and find it curious that in Latin Somnus is sleep and Sona in Hindi is also sleep. I can't help but wonder if there is a deeper PIE connection here given the coincidence of the consonants SN in all these words: Sona - Somnus - Snooze - Usnout

Comment: Etymonline gives [swep-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*swep-) as a common Proto-Indo-European root for sleep related words.

Comment: The pertinant question: Where from did Futurama lift *snu-snu*?

Comment: @vectory, if I remember correctly, it was considered a form of capital punishment in the episode, so possibly from the word "snuff"! It is also common with sex-related words to use a repetition of the same or rhyming word - for example, rumpy-pumpy, hanky-panky, bunga-bunga, and so on.

Comment: Like one of the contributors above I came to this site through study of a Slavonic language, I’m my case Russian. The word заснуть (zasnuts) means to fall asleep. The za is a prefix so I too wondered if the word snooze could have Slavonic roots.

Answer (score 3):

**Snooze** is of uncertain origin according to the Oxford English Dictionary, "[snooze, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183421)":

> apparently a cant or slang word of obscure origin.

The earliest usages establish a general meaning but aren't particularly illuminating for knowing where it comes from.

> 1789   G. Parker Life's Painter xiv. 130   The cull with whom she snooz'd.

Using [Eighteenth Century Collections Online](http://find.galegroup.com/ecco) (university subscription), I found several early entries.

The 1753 edition of *The discoveries of John Poulter, alias Baxter* by J. Poulter include a brief cant lexicon that includes the following:

> The Cull is at Snoos ; the Man is at Sleep

In *The festival of Momus, a collection of comic songs, including the modern and a variety of originals* (1780), this bit appears (p. 69):

[image]

> I **snooze** at the [hummums](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89401) (a Turkish bathhouse) 'till twelve...

*Snooze* also appears in some other song books. Here's *The Town and country songster's companion* (1780-1800), p. 37:

> All higley pigley, pigs in the straw, / We **snooze** without thinking of harm, 'Till a signal that goes, / We jump into our cloaths, / And as fine a confusion as ever you saw / Is the midnight false alarm.

By 1795, Humphry Tristram Potter includes *snooze* in his *A new dictionary of all the cant and flash languages, both ancient and modern*. While Potter's lexicography involves a lot of plagiarism and unreliability (as [Julie Coleman claims in *A History of Cant and Slang Dictionaries Volume II*](https://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199557103.003.0004)), given the evidence above, *snooze* appears to have persisted in *cant* and in other lower registers like popular lyric:

> **SNOOZE**, to sleep

It may be related to other *sn-* nose words (snout, snore) or sleep-related words (doze, drouse, snug), but that's guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

I came here due to my studies of the Polish language. I noted that the Polish noun for "sleep" is "sen", which changes to "snu" in certain grammatical cases. (As you may know, Polish nouns can have multiple different forms.) I usually try to think of mnemonics to help me remember Polish words and I noted with interest that "snu" sounds very much like "snooze". There's little doubt in my mind that the "s-n" construction for "sleep" is an ancient Proto-Indo-European root.

https://www.wordreference.com/plen/snu

Comment: In Russian "fall asleep" is заснуть . zahsnoot. Observe the snooo sound. Switching "za" to the end of the word, snooo - za . Should be a related word.

Answer (score 1):

The [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/pgw5imq)  suggests an earlier usage, but adds no details about its origin:

> 1753 [UK] J. Poulter Discoveries (1774) 43: *The Cull is at Snoos; The Man is asleep.*

In the following interesting extract from [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/03/a-nosy-question.html), they notice that a number of English terms related to  “nose” are ultimately related to old German “snut”, but still snooze appears to have a misterious origin:

> The words “snot,” “snotty,” “snout,” “snoot,” “snooty” (in the sense of looking down one’s nose) and “schnoz” are all related to a similar prehistoric Germanic root associated with the nose, “snut.”
>
> “Snob” is unrelated, ***and “snooze” is of uncertain origin.*** But “snitch,” meaning an informer, may be related to a 17th-century word for a fillip on the nose. So there may be a connection there.

Comment: The instance in Poulter's [_Discoveries_](https://books.google.com/books?id=rddbAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22John+Poulter%22+Discoveries&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipi5zmuo3iAhUrhlQKHUi2CIwQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22cull%20is%20at%20snoos%22&f=false), seventh edition (1754) appears in a glossary titled "An Explanation of the Language of Thieves, Commonly Called Cant," without any elaboration beyond the direct translation: "The Cull is at Snoos ; _the Man is at Sleep_."

Answer (score 0):

- According to Wiktionary, 'snooze' can be compared to the Dutch 'snoezelen' (to snooze).
- Further web searching suggests that the word is also akin to the Low German 'snusen' or Danish 'snuse'.

What this suggests is that 'snooze' most likely came from a variety of words meaning 'sleep' in other languages, making it entirely possible that 'usnout' is a distant relative of 'snooze'.